# Determine how many messages are shown on JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I would expect a very easy way to know how many messages are currently shown with JSQMessagesViewController. Couldn't find any directly asking the controller. Is there?

Comment: How are you passing the data in `JSQMessagesViewController `

Comment: @Rajatp I'm using this code:
https://github.com/relatedcode/NotificationChat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total number of available messages:

```
 // If you don't have multiple sections, simply go get the number of message in the first section
 NSInteger numberOfAvailableMessages = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
```

Pay attention to call that after the data has been already loaded to the screen.

Comment: It depends on the `timing` that you try to get it though. If the UICollectionView data hasn't been loaded at least once, off course there is nothing to count from it. Can you let me know about this?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Sadly bounty was given automatically to the wrong answer (for some reason people vote for it).

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer was helpful. StackOverflow isn't perfect, no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

In query.limit, you can set the number of displayed messages. Even I was trying to get the grips with this, but saw an implementation from JesseHu on his chat example.

```
func loadMessages() {
    if self.isLoading == false {
        self.isLoading = true
        var lastMessage = messages.last

        var query = PFQuery(className: <your class name>)
        query.whereKey(PF_CHAT_GROUPID, equalTo: groupId)// query params
        if lastMessage != nil {
            query.whereKey(PF_CHAT_CREATEDAT, greaterThan: lastMessage?.date)
        }
        query.includeKey(PF_CHAT_USER)
        query.orderByDescending(PF_CHAT_CREATEDAT)
        query.limit = 25
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = false
                for object in (objects as! [PFObject]!).reverse() {
                    self.addMessage(object)
                }
                if objects.count > 0 {
                    self.finishReceivingMessage()
                    self.scrollToBottomAnimated(false)
                }
                self.automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true
            } else {
                println("Network error")
            }
            self.isLoading = false;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change how many messages I load but to check how many messages are currently showing on the view...